# Delphi exception class Segmentation (11) caused by thread?

Tags: multithreading, delphi

When ButtonConnectClick is activated it gives the Segmentation (11) exception.
I think it's caused by `pocForm1.AddLine('new line by thread');` in the thread, but I'm not sure how to solve it.

The idea is to add lines to the memo field while the thread is active.

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  System.SysUtils, System.Types, System.UITypes, System.Classes, System.Variants,
  FMX.Types, FMX.Controls, FMX.Forms, FMX.Graphics, FMX.Dialogs,
  IdBaseComponent, IdComponent, IdTCPConnection, IdTCPClient, FMX.Layouts,
  FMX.Memo, FMX.StdCtrls, IdGlobal, IdIntercept;

type
  TpocForm1 = class(TForm)
    ButtonConnect: TButton;
    ButtonDisconnect: TButton;
    Memo1: TMemo;
    procedure ButtonConnectClick(Sender: TObject);
    procedure ButtonDisconnectClick(Sender: TObject);
    procedure AddLine(text : String);

  private

  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

  TpocTCPClientThread = class(TThread)
    //TCPClient: TIdTCPClient;
  protected
    procedure Execute; override;
  end;

var
  pocForm1: TpocForm1;

implementation
{$R *.fmx}
var
  thread: TpocTCPClientThread;

procedure TpocForm1.ButtonConnectClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Memo1.Lines.Add('Client connected with server');
  thread:= TpocTCPClientThread.Create(False);
end;

procedure TpocForm1.ButtonDisconnectClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  thread.Terminate;
  thread.WaitFor;
  FreeAndNil(thread);
  Memo1.Lines.Add('Client disconnected from server');
end;

procedure TpocForm1.AddLine(text : String);
begin
  Memo1.Lines.Add(text);
end;


procedure TpocTCPClientThread.Execute();
begin
  while not Terminated do
  begin
    pocForm1.AddLine('new line by thread');
  end;
end;

end.
```

Comment: Use *File->New->Other->Delphi Projects->Delphi Files->Thread Object*, and then read the large comment at the top of that new unit. You could also just read the [TThread documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE7/en/System.Classes.TThread), particularly the last bullet point under *Following are issues and recommendations to be aware of when using threads*.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot execute GUI code from outside the main thread. You need to ensure that all your GUI code executes on the main thread. For instance by calling `TThread.Queue` or `TThread.Synchronize`.